# EntityFramework Raw SQL Insert with Output Not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-insert

I have the following code:

```
    [HttpPost, Authorize]
    public int AddLocation([FromBody]dynamic formBody)
    {

        List<object> parameters = new List<object>();

        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("companyID", (int)formBody.companyID));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("locationName", (string)formBody.locationName));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("locationCode", (string)formBody.locationCode));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("locationDescription", (string)formBody.locationDescription));


        string addStmt = "INSERT INTO INV_LOCATIONS (NAME, CODE, DESCRIPTION, COMPANY_ID) OUTPUT inserted.ID VALUES (@locationName, @locationCode, @locationDescription, @companyID)";
        var output = database.Database.SqlQuery<int>(addStmt, parameters);
        var test = output.First();
        SqlParameter[] parameters2 = {
            new SqlParameter("locationID", output),
            new SqlParameter("quantity", (int)formBody.quantity),
            new SqlParameter("partID", (int)formBody.partID)
        };
        string SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO INV_QUANTITY (PART_ID, LOCATION_ID, QUANTITY) VALUES (@partID, @locationID, @quantity)";
        var stmtExecute = database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SqlStatement, parameters2);
        return output.First();
    }
```

I cannot get the OUTPUT or that insert in general to run. When I copy that query directly to SSMS and replace the parameters with the passed values I get the outputted ID and the new row is created. I checked all the parameters and they are there and working. I have done something similar to this before and it worked but this one is not working. The working version is slightly different but I tried the working code and still it did not work here.

Working Code:

```
        string SqlStatement = 
            "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GLOBAL_CATEGORIES WHERE CATEGORY_NAME = @catName) " +
            "BEGIN " +
                "INSERT INTO GLOBAL_CATEGORIES (CATEGORY_NAME, MODIFIED_BY, DATE_CREATED, DATE_LAST_UPDATED) OUTPUT inserted.CATEGORY_ID VALUES (@catName, @modifiedBy, @date, @date)" +
            "END " +
            "ELSE SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM GLOBAL_CATEGORIES WHERE CATEGORY_NAME = @catName";

        object[] parameters =
        {
            new SqlParameter("catName", (string)formBody.catName),
            new SqlParameter("modifiedBy", claimUsername),
            new SqlParameter("date", date)
        };

        var globalID = database.Database.SqlQuery<int>(SqlStatement, parameters);
        //var globalID = database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SqlStatement, parameters);

        SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO COMPANY_CATEGORIES (COMPANY_ID, CATEGORY_ID, SORT_ORDER, MODIFIED_BY, DATE_CREATED, DATE_LAST_UPDATED) VALUES (@companyID, @globalID, 0, @modifiedBy, @date, @date)";

        SqlParameter[] parameters2 = {
            new SqlParameter("modifiedBy", claimUsername),
            new SqlParameter("date", date),
            new SqlParameter("companyID", (int)formBody.companyID),
            new SqlParameter("globalID", globalID.ToList().ToArray()[0])
        };
```

In the working version, I did a `.ToList().ToArray()[0]` to get the value. I get the following error with the code I have now and even if I use the "working" code:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native type.'
```

Any Ideas? I am more than happy to share any more detail if it will help.